# EF what happens when we alter database schema while app is running

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a webapp uses EF, and a separated EF migration project.

The webapp is deployed and running.

Now I manually run EF migration which alter the db schemas, which make it very different from before.

So what will happen to the running webapp? Does it crash? What is best way to handle this situation?

Comment: schedule the update put out-of-hours, or take the app off-line first.  the risk is losing data during a save operation.

Comment: Yes it will crash if you removed columns, change stored name, parameters, column names, table name etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Code First (that apparently you are), it will crash with the following error:

> The model backing the 'dbContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created.

Otherwise, depending on the changes you have made (that seem to be a lot) it still has a good chance of crashing.
A safe approach is to first stop the app and then update the database and the app.